# C# UnitTest Async Method Error - System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, httpclient, moq

Hi I have a window services project that I already successfully implement to the server. But I have to create unit test which I stuck for weeks to solve it. Can any of you guys help me?

> - I have clean the project several time and the issue come out when I try to setup the Mock based on my interface
> - I also have refactoring the code several time but fail to run the
>     unittest :(

Here is my code:

**Interface**

```
public interface IJobScheduler
{
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetASync(HttpClient client, string destination, CancellationTokenSource cancelToken);
    Task<bool> RunJobAgent(HttpClient client);
}
```

**Class** *(purposely create to inject data using unit test)*

```
public class JobSchedular
{
    private IJobScheduler iJobScheduler;

    public JobSchedular(IJobScheduler ijobscheduler) => iJobScheduler = ijobscheduler;

    public JobSchedular() => iJobScheduler = new JobSchedularSvc();
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetASync(HttpClient client, string destination, CancellationTokenSource cancelToken)
  {
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> result = iJobScheduler.GetASync(client, destination, cancelToken);
    return await result;
  }
}
```

**Actual Class**

```
    public partial class JobSchedularSvc : ServiceBase, IJobScheduler
    {   
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetASync(HttpClient client, string destination, CancellationTokenSource cancelToken)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response;// = new HttpResponseMessage();
                using (client)
                {
                    response = await client.GetAsync(destination, cancelToken.Token);
                }

                return response;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogHandler.InsertLog(LogLevel.Error, $"FAILED: GetAsync() - {ex.Message}", ex.StackTrace, "JobSchedulerSvc", "JobSchedulerSvc", null, null, null, null).Wait();
                return null;
            }

        }
}
```

**Test Method**

```
   public async Task Test()
    {
        var message = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        JobScheduler = new Mock<IJobScheduler>();

        JobScheduler.Setup(test => test.GetASync(It.IsAny<HttpClient>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationTokenSource>()))
            .Returns(Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage() { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK, Content = new StringContent("{'Result':true,'Exception':[]}") }));

        CancellationTokenSource cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var response = new JobSchedular(JobScheduler.Object).GetASync(new HttpClient(), "/api/job/runjobagent", cancelToken);

        var result = await response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        Assert.AreEqual(result, "{'Result':true,'Exception':[]}");
    }
```

I just want to call the local function GetAsync() which returns httpResponseMessage

Comment: I reproduced this with your code and could run the test successfully. Though I see you intend to test "Actual Class", but you are mocking it.

Answer (score 0):

I edit the .csproj file and add this line it works

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```